# Chazon Ish understanding of "Baruch"

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, chazon-ish

A recorded shiur from a Rav reported that the Chazon Ish held the kavana of the word "baruch" is "to praise" Hashem. After searching throughout the writings of the Chazon Ish on Orach Chaim, YD, EH, and CM, as well as Orchos Rabbeinu, I haven't found such an idea. Where is that source?

Comment: Maybe mpi hashemuah

Comment: Did you check his famous collection of letters? Also, could you elaborate if you have more details on the distinction of this idea?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Unfortunately, I don't have much more context to add other than it was explaining the meaning of "baruch" - the Rav mentioned the Chazon Ish's understanding of "baruch = praise" is seen in הָשֵׁב תָּשִׁיב לוֹ אֶת־הַעֲבוֹט כְּבֹא הַשֶׂמֶשׁ וְשָׁכַב בְּשַׂלְמָתוֹ וּבֵרֲכֶךָּ וּלְךָ תִּהְיֶה צְדָקָה לִפְנֵי ה' אֱלֹקיךָ.

Comment: See this [*kuntrus* ברוך אתה](https://hebrewbooks.org/63910); in the [first chapter](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=63910&st=&pgnum=14&hilite=) he discusses myriads of sources on the topic which also suggests that this is not unique to the Chazon Ish.

Comment: Did you check Emuna U'Vitachon?